# How to covert HTML collection to an array, that gets updated as per DOM

Tags: javascript, arrays, htmlcollection

I am creating DOM elements dynamically through JS and was trying to log them out after they were created. And then i want to convert them to an array.

But while trying, when i log DOM as HTML collection, it shows a non-empty collection, but when i convert it to the array, using different methods, then it shows an empty array.

Here is my code:

```
console.log('Collection ', elements.selectButtons);
console.log('Collection Length ', elements.selectButtons.length);
console.log('Object values ', Object.values(elements.selectButtons));
console.log('Object entries ', Object.entries(elements.selectButtons));
console.log('Object keys ', Object.keys(elements.selectButtons));
console.log('Array Converting ', [...elements.selectButtons]);
console.log('JSON Stringify', JSON.stringify(elements.selectButtons));
console.log('Collection', elements.selectButtons);
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Can someone please tell, how to convert dynamically updated HTML Collection to non-empty array.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a timing issue.

`console.log`s are automatically updated when logging 'live' objects.
E.g.

```js
let nestedArr = {arr: []};
console.log(nestedArr); // {arr: [5]}
nestedArr.arr.push(5);
```

But this doesn't work for primitives or temporary objects:

```js
let nestedArr = {arr: []};
console.log(nestedArr.arr.length); // 0
console.log([...nestedArr.arr]); // []
nestedArr.arr.push(5);
```

To demonstrate with your example:

```js
let parent = document.querySelector('#parent');
let children = parent.children;
let addChild = () => parent.append(document.createElement('span'));

console.log('children ', children);
console.log('children length ', children.length);
console.log('Object values ', Object.values(children));
console.log('Object entries ', Object.entries(children));
console.log('Object keys ', Object.keys(children));
console.log('Array  ', [...children]);
console.log('JSON stringify', JSON.stringify(children));
console.log('children', children);

addChild();
addChild();
addChild();
addChild();
addChild();
```

```html
<div id="parent"></div>
```

Of course, this is a feature of the browser console and isn't a given that all browsers and cli's will behave the same. The above examples work in chrome, so make sure you have the browser console open when running.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the concept.

Can you please tell me how to convert that HTML collection to a non-empty array then?

Comment: `[...collection]` is the correct way to convert a **non-empty** collection into a **non-empty** array. There's no way to convert an **empty** collection into a **non-empty** array.

Comment: I used [...collection] but that also gives empty array. But the collection is not empty..

Comment: The collection **is** empty **when** you spread it `[...collection]`. Read my answer.

Comment: But then how to achieve it to be non-empty like the collection in console.log(collection)

Comment: @Amaogi What is being said is you are not adding anything to the list before the console log statements (thus the list is empty). You would need to move the log statements after you do the adding in order for the primitives you log to show as non empty. So you need stuff in your collection before you do the conversion to list.

Comment: @Aaron Ohk, Thanks a lot!